# SSRS - How to use a value from a different dataset as the X-axis in a chart

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts

I'm a beginner, and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 for creating a report. I'm trying to configure a line chart with one variable for the values and another variable for the x-axis.

The problem is that I can only use one field, "VALUE" for the values, which first made me think that I need two datasets in one chart. I have tried to set the second dataset as the x-axis by writing `=Sum(Fields!VALUE.Value, "Dataset2")` as an expression in the label and group expression of "Category Groups," but that did not work.

The second option I tried including both variables in one dataset. Now the problem was showing the values with one variable and showing the x-axis with the other variable, all from one field. I tried adding a Filter in "Category Groups" as such:
 Expression: =Fields!VARIABLE.Value
 Operator: =
 Value: BatchTimer
My intention was to show from the two variables in the dataset only the variable BatchTimer on the x-axis. But this did not work either.

Comment: It sounds like you just want the `BatchTimer` field as the chart's Category Group and the `VALUE` field as the Values. If you want to filter the `BatchTimer` with a Parameter, the filter would have an Expression: `BatchTimer` field Operator: `=` and value of the parameter (`Parameters.Timer.Value`). Not sure what `Fields!VARIABLE.Value` is tho.

Comment: @HannoverFist the two fields I can use are "VALUE" and "VARIABLE." "BatchTimer" and "Level" are the two variables in the database file. You're right that I want "BatchTimer" as the Category Group.